# Conditional subtraction on SQL

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

I would like to write a case statement to subtract the lowest datetime between app login and portal login from the signup time.

I am assuming this would involve a case statement, but not sure how to write this out

My current code is:

```
select case when first_app_login < first_portal_login
                then signup_complete - first_app_login
            when first_app_login > first_portal_login
                then signup_complete - first_portal_login
            else signup_complete - first_app_login
       end as signup_to_login
from database
```

However this returns the following error message:

> ERROR: Invalid protocol sequence 'P' while in PortalSuspended state.
>   Untitled Chart

Here is a sample of my data:

```
signup_complete               first_app_login     first_portal_login
2019-07-08 08:38:56.523                          2019-09-07 19:01:01.915
2019-05-10 12:24:11.704     2019-05-10 12:54:11.704
```

The desired result would be signup_complete - first_portal_login for the first row, signup_complete - first_app_login for the second row.

So we only subtract signup_complete with either the non null value or the lowest datetime value between first_app and first_portal login

Comment: Your 1st when is redundant. Don't you have to use `DATEDIFF` in Redshift to calculate a datetime difference?

Comment: @emm Is this formula correct: `signup_complete - first_app_login` or `signup_complete - first_portal_login`? It will always result in negative value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the difference in days there you go. Otherwise you will have to put "month" or "year" on the first parameter of DATEDIFF():

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN first_app_login < first_portal_login THEN 
        DATEDIFF(day, signup_complete, first_app_login)
    WHEN first_app_login > first_portal_login THEN 
        DATEDIFF(day, signup_complete, first_portal_login)
    ELSE DATEDIFF(day, signup_complete, (case
                                WHEN first_app_login IS NULL THEN
                                    first_portal_login
                                WHEN first_portal_login IS NULL THEN
                                    first_app_login
                                END))
END AS signup_to_login FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
```

If you just want to subtract dates as you were doing:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN first_app_login < first_portal_login THEN 
        signup_complete - first_app_login
    WHEN first_app_login > first_portal_login THEN 
        signup_complete - first_portal_login
    ELSE signup_complete - (case
                                WHEN first_app_login IS NULL THEN
                                    first_portal_login
                                WHEN first_portal_login IS NULL THEN
                                    first_app_login
                                END)
END AS signup_to_login FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
```

Comment: Is this formula correct: `signup_complete - first_app_login` or `signup_complete - first_portal_login`? It will always result in negative value.

Comment: I personally don't know, I tried to stick to what the question was but you are right, It would result on a negative value

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `LEAST` function. `LEAST` function's [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GREATEST_LEAST.html) states that it will *"return the smallest value and ignores the `NULL` values"*.

```
SELECT LEAST(first_app_login, first_portal_login) - signup_complete as signup_to_login from dummy_table;
```

Here you can see it in action for **Postgres 8.4 DB** on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=d3f071cbc1bde12d95f7cc8779a97aee).

Comment: The reason I tested it out on the Postgres database is that I didn't have access to Amazon Redshift database. Secondly *Amazon Redshift is also based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2* so probably it should work for you as well.